# Label Won't Disappear with Input on ng-show

Tags: angularjs

```
<input
    bs-form-control

    id="new_password"
    type="text"
    ng-model="device.new_password"
    ng-show="on_reset"
    ng-minlength="8"
    name="newPassword"
    label="New Password"
    class="col-xs-9 col-sm-10 col-lg-11"
    value="{{Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);}}"
   />
```

When I have $scope.on_reset = false then the input certainly disappears, as intended.  But I would like its associated label to disappear as well.  When I take it out, it appears as "undefined" on the HTML DOM.  If I replace "New Password" with the empty string then it keeps the label there, but if I try to add a hard coded label, the label isn't inside the calculated form-group row from angularjs trying to be smart and cool.

Is there something I can do about making the label disappear with the input when ng-show is false?

Comment: Can you post your form-group as well, and a plunker perhaps?

Comment: Is there also a `<label>` tag that accompanies this `<input>`? Why can't you apply `ng-show` to their parent or to both?

Comment: Ah okay, I will have to wrap a div around this input tag and then apply the ng-show to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the input in a div which has the ng-show directive.  Take the ng-show out of the input tag because it would be redundant now.